# Avoid scrolling scrollable elements when scrolling the page using the mousewheel

Tags: javascript, scrollwheel

How can one prevent scrolling scrollable elements (e.g. text area, div with scrollbars) when using the mouse wheel to scroll the page?

when I use the mouse wheel to scroll the page vertically from top to bottom, I would like to ignore scrollable elements which happen to turn up under the mouse cursor.

I still want to scroll the "scrollable elements" when not scrolling the page but rather just hovering over the element and using the scroll wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the plugin `jquery-mousewheel` ([get it here](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)) and doing something like this:

```
$('.scrollable').mousewheel(function(e) {
   return false;
}
```

Where you add the class `scrollable` to said scrollable items.

Comment: edited my question; I still want to be able to scroll the elements when not scrolling the page, but just hover the element and using the scroll wheel...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with css :

```
.something {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.something:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lx7a1v6/

Comment: Does not work (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lx7a1v6/1/)). when you scroll the page and the div is scrolled 'under the mouse cursor', the div is scolled instead of the page.